Maximum shebang size exceeded on Yocto build
I'm trying to make yocto recipe for python package pypng, but I'm still getting error /work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/pypng/0-r0/packages-split/pypng/usr/bin/pripamtopng maximum shebang size exceeded, the maximum size is 128. I have tried to reduce recipe name and version lengths, in hope, the size was exceeded just by little, but it didn't help. Then I have tried to recompile kernel on my build machine with BINPRM_BUF_SIZE 512, which should solve this problem, but it didn't. I'm still getting the maximum size is 128. Do you have any idea, what can I do with it?

Changing BINPRM_BUF_SIZE should allow you to work around this. Did you forget to reboot, or to install the new kernel?

If the binary path is too long, move the binary, or create a symlink in a more convenient place.
For example,
ln -s /work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/pypng/0-r0/packages-split/pypng/usr/bin/pripamtopn /usr/local/bin

creates a symlink /usr/local/bin/primatopnm which you can use in the shebang line instead of the overlong original.
#!/usr/local/bin/primatopnm -options

You need root or sudo access to create a symlink in /usr/local/bin; but you can create it in your home directory or wherever if you prefer.
(The path is only 100 characters long. Either your real path is a
even longer, or it has a substantial number of options, too.)
Alternatively, if /work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/pypng was your current directory when you ran the packaging tool, move that to a location with a shorter path, or create a symlink to it.
ln -s /work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/pypng /tmp/x

will allow you to use /tmp/x/0-r0/packages-split/pypng/usr/bin/pripamtopn in the shebang line.
(You might not be able to execute anyting in /tmp; otherwise, you could even symlink the binary to /tmp/y and use that in the shebang.)
